# Can't access a nested object attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this confusing problem where I can access a nested object property but not the other.

In my react application I make a request call, this is the result

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Apprenez les bases de donnee",
        "shortDescription": null,
        "description": "Cours khfif drif",
        "requirements": [],
        "outcomes": [],
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "nom": "Programation",
            "sousCategories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nom": "Base de donnees",
                    "dateAjout": "2020-07-19",
                    "dateModif": null
                }
            ],
            "dateAjout": "2020-07-18",
            "dateModif": null,
            "fontAwesomeIcon": "fa-desktop\r\n",
            "thumbnail": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468070454955-c5b6932bd08d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
        },
        "sousCategorie": {
            "id": 1,
            "nom": "Base de donnees",
            "dateAjout": "2020-07-19",
            "dateModif": null
        },
        "prix": 199.99,
        "isSolde": null,
        "prixSolde": null,
        "niveau": "Debutant",
        "thumbnail": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489875347897-49f64b51c1f8?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80",
        "videoUrl": null,
        "dateAjout": null,
        "dateModification": null,
        "isVisible": null,
        "statut": "",
        "plateformHost": null,
        "metaKeyword": null,
        "metaDescription": null,
        "langue": "Francais",
        "professeur": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Abass",
            "lastName": "J EE",
            "email": "Abass@JEE.com",
            "password": "abass",
            "biographie": "Rajel Mzyan",
            "role": "admin",
            "dateAjout": "2020-07-18",
            "dateModif": null,
            "historique": [],
            "wishList": [],
            "cours": []
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Apprenez la programation",
        "shortDescription": null,
        "description": "Cours zwine",
        "requirements": [],
        "outcomes": [],
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "nom": "Programation",
            "sousCategories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "nom": "Base de donnees",
                    "dateAjout": "2020-07-19",
                    "dateModif": null
                }
            ],
            "dateAjout": "2020-07-18",
            "dateModif": null,
            "fontAwesomeIcon": "fa-desktop\r\n",
            "thumbnail": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468070454955-c5b6932bd08d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
        },
        "sousCategorie": null,
        "prix": 199.99,
        "isSolde": null,
        "prixSolde": null,
        "niveau": "Debutant",
        "thumbnail": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557853197-aefb550b6fdc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=675&q=80",
        "videoUrl": null,
        "dateAjout": null,
        "dateModification": null,
        "isVisible": null,
        "statut": "",
        "plateformHost": null,
        "metaKeyword": null,
        "metaDescription": null,
        "langue": "Francais",
        "professeur": {
            "id": 2,
            "firstName": "rabie",
            "lastName": "majdoul",
            "email": "rabie@spring.com",
            "password": "rabie123",
            "biographie": "Rajel mzyan tahowa",
            "role": "etudiant",
            "dateAjout": "2020-07-01",
            "dateModif": null,
            "historique": [],
            "wishList": [],
            "cours": []
        }
    }
]
```

In my react app I store this object in a redux state called cours and I access it with map()

```
  props.cours.map((cours) => {
                        console.log(
                          JSON.stringify(cours.category) +
                            "\n" +
                            JSON.stringify(cours.professeur)
                        );
                        return (
                          <div className=" col-sm">
                            <CourseCard
                              title={cours.title}
                              subtitle={
                                cours.professeur.firstName +
                                "  " +
                                cours.professeur.lastName
                              }
                              tag={cours.category.nom}
                              bgPhoto={cours.thumbnail}
                              totalReviews={30}
                              ratingAverage={cours.rating}
                            />
                          </div>
                        );
                      })
```

Both `professeur` and `category` are defined https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekVH6.jpg,
accessing `professeur.firstName` and `professeur.lastName` don't cause a problem, but accessing `category.nom` returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom' of undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the cause of the problem with a friend, i was using a placeholder in my initial state

```
const initialState = {
  //Index
  bannerTitle: "Apprenez à votre rythme",
  bannerSubTitle:
    "Étudiez n'importe quel sujet, à tout moment. Choisissez parmi des milliers de cours dirigés par des experts .",
  //Header
  categories: [
    
  isPending: false,

  cours: [
{
title:"test",
rating:5
}],
 
};
```

removing `cours` values solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Look like nothing wrong in render code.

Can you please make sure while rendering component category or category.nom object has value.

Please try to `console.log(cours.category)`.

Comment: It works flawlessly ,https://i.imgur.com/yZNmbyw.jpg